# In Linux I have different color for the same thing than in Windows

Tags: windows, xfce, unity, color-management

The colors in Windows are much less saturated. Why is that? The fonts are much more crisper. I have installed msfonts in Ubuntu and it's better, but still the Windows fonts are different. Check the screenshot I have done from both systems in the same browser. The colors are much more saturated in all browsers on Linux.

Here is the difference:
**[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eaai3.png)**

And here is the detail (notice the yellow and green instead of green on Linux):
**[Image - detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qE4ZY.jpg)**

The font on Windows is more crisp and easier to read. The Xubuntu fonts no matter if I use Droid, DeJaVu, Ubuntu etc. is painful for my eyes.

Why do I have different colors for the same things in Windows and Linux? I have tried Chrome and Firefox in both Linux (Xubuntu) and Windows and Windows versions have the colors less saturated and more darker so it's more pleasant to read. Also, the fonts are not so bold and they are much easier to read than in Linux.

I have noticed the same color issue in Ubuntu's Unity too.

If you have a little time and can do a screenshot, please, upload a portion of a Google results search (like mine) so I (and others) can see if you have different colors or the same colors as me. Thank you.

**UPDATE:**
As I have found out [[here]](http://blog.codinghorror.com/whats-wrong-with-apples-font-rendering/) and [[here]](http://blog.codinghorror.com/font-rendering-respecting-the-pixel-grid/) the problem I am facing is probably the missing font smoothing technique called ClearType by Microsoft on Linux/Apple machines. Linux/Apple use a different approach when rendering fonts. Microsoft use ClearType technology and others use some other antialiasing technology. In short, smaller fonts looks less blurry in Windows and are harder to read on Linux/Mac. Which is useful while using a browser all the day. I simply cannot use a browser on Linux and Mac. My head starts aching and the eyestrain is really bad and my body tells my go back to Windows.

Comment: To my eyes, the linux looks way less saturated than the windows. However, that's irrelevant, first of all, the only way you can actually run this test is to create a simple html page, that has the fonts strictly assigned via css, then view those pages. And the only meaningful test there is to determine if apples vs apples are the same, that is, install a standard windows font on linux, then create the test page, then view the page on chrome/firefox in windows / gnu/linux. Right now you are simply making a comment about default fonts used by firefox/chrome, which has almost no meaning.

Comment: @Lizardx Please, post your image of a zoomed in google search result from your DE, so , we can compare the colors. It can be from firefox, chrome or chromium. They all have the same issue in Linux.

Comment: [this wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Font_configuration) seems to have a lot more to say on the subject than you talk about. maybe theres more to it? i looked at your pictures, and i wasn't terribly impressed with any differences, but if you see it you see it. i just find it hard to believe that Microsoft has pigeon-holed the font-market. seems more like apple's style to me.

Comment: The smaller font's are easier to read with ClearType then the other font rendering techniques. That's why Mac guys like the huge letter spacing and huge and bold fonts ;) I am sure you have noticed that. On the same resolution e.g. 1920x1080, the bigger fonts look better on Mac, LInux. But the smaller fonts (typical scenario while browsing the web) are easier to read (less blurry) on Windows. Microsoft has specifically done this with ClearType so the small fonts are easier to read. And I read a lot of 10px +-2px during the day, so, until I buy a 4K monitor, Linux won't be used for web browsing

Comment: or you could change the font size so it doesn't hurt your eyes.

Comment: @cas I am a webdeveloper. I need to see the real things. Otherwise I will be reading everything from the web on my Kindle or on [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sX_IhYLh2Jw)

Comment: ah, is that why you think hard-coding font sizes in pixels (rather than pt or, better yet, em or rem) is a good idea?  a quick google turns up http://www.narga.net/understanding-font-sizing-in-css-em-px-pt-percent-rem/ which isn't a bad quick reference except it makes the mistake of assuming that there's a standard measure of pixels (1px = 1/96 of an inch - which is only roughly true on a 96dpi monitor).  a pixel's size is relative to the monitor it is being displayed on, and is not in any way universal.

Comment: @cas If you implement pixel perfect designs, you need to stick to pixel perfect fonts. If you implement responsive and I-don't-care-a-few-pixels designs you can ignore hard-coded-pixel values like you suggest. Clients and designs are different. Been there, done that.

Comment: so-called "pixel perfect" designs look "perfect" on the monitor of the person who designed them when viewed with the eyes of the designer.  there's no way of knowing how they'll look on **any** other monitor or any other eyes.  more to the point, the correct way to render a web page is "*however the viewer wants it rendered*".  that might be in tiny 10pt font or an enormous 24 or 36pt font or larger because they've got displaced retinas or just aging 40+ eyes. or because they're viewing it on a phone or tablet or on a TV screen 15 feet away.

Comment: @cas The correct way is the client's way. Been there, done that.

Comment: John, I have to honestly say I have no idea what you are talking about. I look at and have looked at big, small, tiny, medium, fonts, on gnu/linux desktops, every day. I do web development. I do pixel perfect, I do small fonts when needed, I do responsive, and I still have absolutely no idea what you're talking about. I think you need to learn a bit more about default fonts. There's no point in anyone posting screenshots because the real question is what the default font is, the graphics drivers (vesa...)To cas: it's not black and white, there are times and places for all font decisions.

Comment: @Lizardx In you own words "it's not just and black" and "honestly", you need to learn more about TrueType and FreeType difference and look at the studies that say that people prefer ClearType font rendering before FreeType. Thank you.

Comment: John, you must be a designer. The installed fonts on a computer define what fonts will be used on a webpage. Hopefully you are aware of the way font family rules work in html/css, though to be honest, it really appears that you don't understand this. The installed fonts on the system define what fonts can be displayed. The default system/browser fonts determine what fonts will be used to display web pages. While I can see the differences in your screenshots, they have no meaning because they simply reflect your defaults and installed fonts, nothing else. This has nothing to do with freetype.

Comment: @Lizardx We got it. we are all idiots and Linux font rendering is superior. Bye.

Comment: John, you're getting quite defensive. I didn't say a word about linux fonts being superior or inferior. I have no idea if you are an idiot or not, but you do seem to be extremely confused about how fonts work in computers and on webpages. I suggest you take some time to learn a bit more before jumping to conclusions about what people are telling you, particularly when you have to put words in my mouth. Now, with that said, my experience with most designers tracks cas, they are not technically very competent as a rule. But that's their fault,, not mine.

Comment: Also, since you can trivially install windows fonts on gnu/linux, even talking about linux vs windows fonts is somewhat odd. I like windows fonts myself, that's why I install them. But I can't make a users computer have them installed, so I can't assume they are present.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, using first a 1920x1200 and (after an upgrade) a 2560x1440 monitor connected via a KVM switch to both Linux and a  Windows 7 desktop machine, the Windows fonts are ghastly - fuzzy, blurry, and difficult to read.

The Linux fonts are crisp, clear, and beautiful to read.  At any resolution.

1920x1200 on Windows was OK-ish but 2560x1440 is horrible, really painful to read...fortunately I don't use the win box for anything except Steam games so I don't spend much time on the Windows desktop and don't care much.  AFAIAC, Windows is just a games console / launcher screen.

Maybe you need to change the default fonts that xfce uses (Settings Manager -> Appearance -> Fonts tab).  I use Deja Vu Sans Book 14 on my 2560x1440 monitor, with Full Hinting, RGB subpixel order, and a custom DPI setting of 96 DPI.  Apart from the font size, I didn't bother (or need to) change any of those settings when I upgraded from WUXGA to 1440p.  I could probably tweak the settings further if I had to, but they're good enough.

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of a zoomed in google result? It can be from firefox, chrome or chromium, I see the same issue in all of them on Linux.

Comment: Sorry, but I have seen this same problem with Linux on all machines. It's not something I have discovered yesterday. I have noticed that 7 years ago on my old HP laptop for the first time. Then on all machines and in every distribution of Linux. It has to be something with the X server or something. Maybe the only solution is the Dell XPS with 4k display. But it's sad that you have to have 4k monitor to have fonts that doesn't hurt your eyes.

Comment: iceweasel (firefox) screenshot in http://taz.net.au/~cas/ulse/.  feel free to download and zoom it.  you don't need a 4K monitor for decent fonts in linux.  They're good on every resolution i've tried since the mid to late 90s (which is about when graphics resolutions started getting good enough to bother switching from text consoles to X), including XGA, WXGA, 1080p, WSXGA, WUXGA, and 1440p.

Comment: I just found [this article](http://blog.codinghorror.com/whats-wrong-with-apples-font-rendering/) and [this article](http://blog.codinghorror.com/font-rendering-respecting-the-pixel-grid/). It seems that Apple and Linux use different approach than Microsoft. That's why the Microsoft's ClearType technology (patented) is better for small fonts and worse for bigger fonts. I finally understand why the Apple guys use always such big and bold fonts for headers etc. ;) and Windows guys are OK with smaller or thinner fonts. I cannot read 10px text on Apple and Linux. It's blurry to me.

Comment: part of the problem is that many web designers are morons and specify font-sizes in hard-coded pixels (px) rather than pt or em units.  this can only possibly look good on the exact screen it was designed on.  it looks lousy on any screen larger than what the designer worked with.  Don't read 10px text on linux or mac or anything.  Read 10pt or 12pt or 14pt text, or whatever looks good to your eyes on your monitor.  i have my iceweasel and chromium and other browsers configured to force a **minimum** font-size of 16 pt on my 2560x1440 screen...because, as i said, many web designers are morons.

Comment: The Stylish plugin is also good for over-riding ugly tiny-font CSS from moronic web designers.  And NoSquint is good for zooming on a per-site basis.

Comment: I don't think that guys that have created Google.com webpage are morons. I think that they do know what they are doing and still the small fonts used in the results, links there looks much better on Windows. On Mac and Linux its blurry and after a while I get a headache and eye strain. That's why I cannot use Linux and Mac for browsing. The text looks muddy in Linux/Apple for me. I think the 4K is my only chance. I love Linux but when I use any browser my body tells me stop and go back to Windows. The eye strain and headache is really bad after a while while browsing on Linux/Apple.

Comment: web designers are web designers, whether they work at google or not.

Comment: I have updated my question and it seems that I will have to stick with Windows ClearType rendering because other font rendering techniques give me headache and eyestrain.

Answer (score 0):

At the current stage of Linux development, there is no distribution/DE that is capable of delivering ClearType-like font rendering where the pixels are forced to stay in the grid. Think of it as a "mono-type-on-pixel-level" thing, where Microsoft's implementation (ClearType) allows better readability for smaller fonts.

Apple's and Linux way of rendering fonts is ignoring the pixel grid rules and there is no pixel-snapping-to-the-grid like feature. That produce very nice headers and bold text, but you will loose readability on small fonts.

So, unless there is a Linux or Mac that will do small font rendering like ClearType from Windows, I cannot use Linux or Mac for my daily web browsing. My head starts hurting and the eyestrain is significanly higher after a few minutes, if not seconds. If I go back to Windows 7 it stops.

Answer (score 0):

If fonts are fuzzy with antialiasing enabled you should probably disable font antialiasing. That will force fonts to take whole pixels.

Getting accurate colors across systems is a huge complicated process.  If you don't want to invest in measurement hardware you should probably look for a gamma compensation/calibration utility that will let you set both systems to at least the same brightness curve and load that into the graphics chip at startup. There's a very good chance Windows is the system out of adjustment if it has more color and contrast.